# Remove "Draft version" header from first page

Tags: draft, aastex

I am using aastex631 to create a document.

```
\documentclass[linenumbers,twocolumn]{aastex631}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

This header appears in it:

[image: Example of how it currently looks.]

How can I remove that for future versions of the document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted aas journals and they say you have to comment out lines 655 through 726 in the aastex631.cls file.  Pretty lame... seems like they should have some kind of option or switch to disable this --- I don't need a "Draft version" header when using aastex to produce a scientific justification or a memo.

Comment: An alternative to commenting out 72 lines is to insert \iffalse before the first of them and \fi after the last. Changing \iffalse to \iftrue to change your mind is a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to disable the command that typesets the header above the title.

```
\documentclass[linenumbers,twocolumn]{aastex631}
\makeatletter
\let\frontmatter@title@above=\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}% for placeholder text
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I took the liberty of filling out your answer to a compilable document. When disabling a command, I prefer the pattern `\let\cmd=\relax` over `\def\cmd{\relax}`. It emphasizes the fact that `\cmd` is being aliased to “do nothing.”

Answer (score 0):

I like the command `\journalinfo{your text here}` in the preamble. This replaces the "Draft version" statement with whatever you want, including a blank field if you just put unprinted characters in the text field.

Answer (score -1):

If you include a line:

```
\submitted{}
```

then the "Draft Version" text is no longer output.

Comment: Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code with your solution for a fast proof? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!